# Completion Handler with asyncTask

Tags: swift

I use Alamofire for send a request. I must rescup a token before to load my viewControler. So, I write a function in app controller (func application).

how  wait the end of process before to go to view controller because I must rescup a token ?

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1.5)
    let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token")
    Helper().alomofireGet(URL: "http://192.168.1.19/app_dev.php/login/app") { JSON in
        print(JSON)
        let token = JSON["csrfToken"].stringValue
        let _: Bool = KeychainWrapper.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
    }
    return true
```

In my classe Helper, I have a function for Alamofire Get.

```
    func alomofireGet(URL: String, onCompletion: @escaping ((_ response: JSON) -> Void)) {
    var contentJSON = JSON()
    Alamofire.request(URL, method: .get).responseJSON() { (reponse) in
        if reponse.result.isSuccess {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.value!)
        } else {
            contentJSON = JSON(reponse.result.error!)
        }
        onCompletion(contentJSON)
    }
}
```

Problem : 
JSON/Token empty -> View Controller -> JSON/Token full
My goal is : 
JSON/Token full -> View Controller

Comment: Better take a controller and make it SplashController and do your operation in that controller. You can show some loader or just the splash image so that app won't look like its frozen.

Comment: Don't *sleep* in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. **Never do that**.